# Stop SAS macro execution on error

Tags: sas

I am running a macro in SAS that occasionally generates errors like this:

> ERROR: Sort execution failure.

The macro continues processing after this error, but I would like to force it to stop further execution. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating the automatic macro variable `&syserr` and conditionally calling `%abort` looks like it should work.

Comment: Definitely seems the most reasonable way to do it.

Comment: If you aren't able to tag your own question as 'answered', someone with enough rep. might want to close this as answered.

Comment: Will do when I can; have to wait two days I think.